# Atajo de teclado en python

Tags: python, tkinter, atajo

Estoy creando un menú en Tkinter, en entorno python. Tengo una opción declarada así:

```
helpmenu.add_command(label = "Acerca de...", accelerator = "Option+R", command = acerca_de) # En el menú Ayuda.
```

Usando el menú con el ratón, me funciona. Al pulsar la opción se dispara la función acerca_de(), que tiene un código muy simple:

```
def acerca_de():
    MessageBox.showinfo("Acerca de...", "Definición de la aplicación")
```

Sin embargo, el atajo de teclado no funciona. He probado a bindearlo así:

```
helpmenu.bind_all("<Option-r>", acerca_de)
```

Es lo que he encontrado en Internet, pero no me funciona.

Estoy en un entorno Mac OS Ventura, con Python 3.8.3. Como puedo hacerlo?

Comment: Parece que no existe el evento `<Option-r>`. Entre la escasa información que encontré sobre la tecla option (o alternate) y una pregunta de SO en inglés, parece que lo que buscas es bindear el evento `<Alt_L>`. Además, no se si te conviene usar bind_all, eso hace que tu función sea llamada sin importar que esté enfocado (por ejemplo, si tenés un toplevel abierto y la ventana principal en segundo plano, y presionas option, la función se ejecutará)

Comment: Esta es la pregunta, por si te sirve. Espero haber podido ayudar c: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41900436/binding-keys-in-mac-os-x-tkinter